# Why top output different from sar output?

Tags: linux, top, sar

This is SLES11sp3 system.

The command top shows the load average of 17+, as shown below:

```
#top
top - 11:59:14 up 19 days, 21:55, 40 users,  load average: 17.09, 17.29, 19.22
Tasks: 514 total,   1 running, 512 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     63996M total,    50885M used,    13111M free,        2M buffers
Swap:     7999M total,        2M used,     7997M free,    47864M cached
```

However the sar output shows very low load:

```
#sar 
11:50:01 AM     all      2.31      0.00      0.19      0.01      0.00     97.49
12:00:01 PM     all      0.91      0.00      0.13      0.00      0.00     98.96
```

What's the likely reason the load has such a big difference?

Comment: Both top and sar show ~98% idle. None of the sar numbers shown relate to load average.

Comment: What time did you run the tar and top commands?  Your last sar data is from 12:00, if you started some major process after that it wouldn't show up until 12:10.  Btw, can you include the sar column headings, different implementations put the columns in different order.  I have no idea what those columns are supposed to represent.